# Drupal subsite status report not showing correct profile

Tags: 8, installation-profiles

I have installed a Drupal site with lightning profile and exported all the configuration in to `/config/default` folder using `drush config-export` command.

After that I have created a subsite and the subsite is installed with a custom profile which depends on lightning profile.

But after installation in subsite status report it is showing that Installed profile is 'lightning' instead of my custom profile.

Am I missing anything? Is there any additional parameters to be added in custom profile?

Comment: Did you copy settings.php? The profile is stored in there now, maybe it hasn’t been updated and Drupal uses that setting for the status report

Comment: I checked settings.php file. Its updated with custom profile. But still showing lightning in status report.

Comment: @Clive, I am using acquia blt project. https://github.com/acquia/blt/issues/2930

Comment: Problem could occures if `sites.php` isn't available or readable. It should be situated on your sites folder on `./sites/sites.php` Have a look at the [Multisite Drupal 8 Setup](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multisite/multisite-drupal-8-setup) for more information.